# Largest circle in area of 3 overlapping circles

Tags: geometry, circles

Suppose I have 3 circles with identical radius,$R$ overlapping each other, with the distance of the center between them to be $d_{12}$, $d_{23}$, $d_{13}$ respectively. What is the largest radius,$r$ of the circle that I can fit in the overlapping areas?

If it is just 2 circles, I think the largest possible circle in the overlapping area is $$r = R-\frac{1}2d$$
given that $d\leq2R$

But I am stumped if it comes to 3 circles. I thought of finding the $r$ if I only look at 2 circles each time, and from there look for the smallest $r$. However, by looking from drawings, I don't think it is correct.
$$r=min(r_{12},r_{23},r_{13})$$
Where $r_{xy}$ is the r relative to 2 circles.

I am not sure if I worded my questions clearly, and I will gladly add any additional .

Trying to find the $r$ of the red circle:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\Delta ABC$ be the triangle with the centres of three circles as its vertices.  For the same radii, the radical axes of two circles are the perpendicular bisectors of each sides $a$, $b$ and $c$.  Hence, they are concurrent at the circumcentre.  Now the circumcentre $O$ is equidistance to the vertices.  The required radius is just the difference between $R$ and the circumradius, that is

\begin{align}
  r &= R-\frac{abc}{4\Delta} \\
  &= R-\frac{abc}{4\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}} \\
  &= R-\frac{abc}{\sqrt{(a+b+c)(b+c-a)(c+a-b)(a+b-c)}} \\
\end{align}

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of generality, suppose the circles have equations
$$\begin{align}
x^2 + y^2 &= R^2 \\
(x-h_1)^2 + y^2 &= R^2 \\
(x-h_2)^2 + (y-k_2)^2 &= R^2.
\end{align}$$
Then the circle of largest radius that is internally tangent to all three circles will have center $(h, k)$ and radius $r$ satisfying
$$\begin{align}
h^2 + k^2 &= (R-r)^2 \\
(h-h_1)^2 + k^2 &= (R-r)^2 \\
(h-h_2)^2 + (k-k_2)^2 &= (R-r)^2.
\end{align}$$
This is a system of three equations in the three unknowns $h, k, r$; however, it is easy to see that we must always have $$h = \frac{h_1}{2}.$$  The solutions for the other variables are left as an exercise.

The only remaining issue is to relate $h_1, h_2, k_2, R$ to the distances $d_{12}, d_{23}, d_{31}$, which is straightforward.